# Regex with Qt capture some text

Tags: c++, regex, qt, capture, qstring

I would like to capture second occurence of the text replaced by a star in the following string:

```
&nbsp;SW * <br>
```

ie string starting with `&nbsp;SW` ending with `<br>` in a QString, using the RegEx with Qt.

an example here: the string is

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;SW = min(1, max(0, pow(10, -0.2 - 6.5 ) ** (1.0 / 0.2)))<br>
```

and expected result is

```
= min(1, max(0, pow(10, -0.2 - 6.5 ) ** (1.0 / 0.2)))
```

So far, i have `QRegExp rx("^[\&nbsp;SW](.*)[<br>]$");` which is not compiling.

How would you do ?

Comment: I'd start with a tutorial about Regular expressions. Look at some examples and how you have to write syntax. Then, try some example lines with an online regexp tester, and start working from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation issue is probably due to trying to escape the ampersand (`\&`). But other than that, your regex is mostly right, just overusing character groups (`[]`), they are not for grouping. This expression works in my tests: `&nbsp;SW(.*)<br>`, so in your case you'd do something like

```
QRegExp rx("&nbsp;SW(.*)<br>")
```

Answer (score 0):

the exact pattern was `QLatin1String(".*&nbsp;SW([^<]*)<br>.*")` and for capture this code was working for me

```
       QRegExp rx(QLatin1String(".*&nbsp;SW([^<]*)<br>.*"));

       int p = 0;
       QString cap ;
       if((p = rx.indexIn(str, p)) != -1) 
           cap = rx.cap(1).trimmed();
```

nota bene: should capture first occurrence for element within the parenthesis with `cap(1)` and not `cap(0)` which capture of the whole pattern and not the content of the parenthesis.